# Git: How to delete the remote branch?

Tags: git

I have a remote branch on git which I want to delete (`remotes/me/ntopng`).

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/me/ntopng
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/go
  remotes/origin/master
```

But when trying to delete it getting this:

```
$ git push origin :remotes/me/ntopng
Username for 'https://github.com': Drewshg312
Password for 'https://Drewshg312@github.com':
remote: Permission to Homebrew/homebrew.git denied to Drewshg312.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

So I swithched to https://github.com/Drewshg312/homebrew.git doing:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Drewshg312/homebrew.git
```

and got:

```
$ git push origin :ntopng
Username for 'https://github.com': Drewshg312
Password for 'https://Drewshg312@github.com':
To https://github.com/Drewshg312/homebrew.git
 - [deleted]         ntopng
```

**BUT** the branch still there

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  pork
  scirius
  remotes/Drewshg312/hb_custom_formulas
  remotes/me/ntopng                <----- STILL THERE!! WTF???
  remotes/me/pork
  remotes/me/scirius
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/go
  remotes/origin/master
```

So how to delete it completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your origin url correct? Currently the original `Homebrew/homebrew` does not have a `ntopng` branch. You are probably not authorized to push to it, either.

If you are intended to push to your forked repo, the origin should be `https://github.com/Drewshg312/homebrew.git`

---

Edit for updated question:

As you see in the output

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  pork
  scirius
  remotes/Drewshg312/hb_custom_formulas
  remotes/me/ntopng          <----- this is another branch on a remote called 'me'
  remotes/me/pork
  remotes/me/scirius
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/go
  remotes/origin/master      <----- no ntopng in origin anymore
```

the remote branch on `origin` has been deleted. It seems you have multiple remote. Try `git remote -v` and see. To delete the branch in remote called `me`, just do what you did for `origin`

```
git push me :ntopng
```

Comment: You are right! but how can I change it to https://github.com/Drewshg312/homebrew.git to be able finally delete the branch?

Comment: @Andrew `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Drewshg312/homebrew.git`

Comment: Check the post now - it's updated

Comment: @Andrew see updates in the answer.